# why angularJs $watch only run once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

codes in the watch run only once .
how can i fix it  ?

```
 this.$rootScope.$watch('tabType', () => {
            if (this.$rootScope["tabType"] === TabType.Sent) {
                this.$scope.refreshSentList();
            } else if (this.$rootScope["tabType"] === TabType.Archive) {
                this.$scope.refreshArchiveList();
            } else if (this.$rootScope["tabType"] === TabType.Inbox) {
                this.$scope.refreshInboxList();
            } else if (this.$rootScope["tabType"] === TabType.Snooz) {
                this.$scope.refreshSnoozList();
            } else if (this.$rootScope["tabType"] === TabType.Trash) {
                this.$scope.refreshTrashList();
            }
        },true);
```

Comment: Uhm, `$watch` works with two parametes `newValue` and `oldValue` maybe that's the problem

Comment: It's more likely that you'll get help if you post a minimal, complete and verifable example, see more at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please give me a sample paulo

Comment: with newValue,oldValue too code is not woring correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example working on ES5, i see you use ES6 if i'm not wrong.

however, that shouldn't affect how `$watch` work

```
$scope.$watch('tabType', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(oldValue);
});
```

Also with `this` on the begining isn't nessesary with `$watch`

Hope this help you

Comment: $watch run for the first time and in the next times i cant console the newValue Or oldValue. infact $watch doesnot run

Comment: This is placed in a controller?  Also, where is placed tabType ?

Comment: i am using UI-Router for routing . is that any effect for using $watch ?

Comment: no, it shouldn't affect it, maybe your controller is recharging, is that a child controller on your view?  or it's the main controller of it?

Comment: its child controller

Comment: ohh, try to move it to your parent controller and check if still happening that problem, it should work

Comment: it have problem in parent controller too

Comment: yes . i tried both of the state with True And Without True

Comment: can you please add your html code or whatever are you using tabType ?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I facing exactly same issue here.

Answer (score 3):

So the probable reason for this issue is that `$watch` is not able to find that element in view when controller initiates. For `$watch` to bind/work the element should be already present in the view.
My guess - You must be using `ng-if` in view.  And `ng-if` creates element only when the condition is true. 
I faced this issue two times and removing `ng-if` worked both times.